# Consume WCF hosted on the web from JQuery on Android

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, wcf, svc

I have successfully hosted a WCF .svc service along with its .NET application on my hosting account @ DiscountASP.net.

The service is now hosted and I can access it from another aspx hosted on the same hosted in the same environment.  In that aspx I use Javascript code to access it and its working fine.

Now, what I am trying to achieve here is, access that same service from somewhere else on the web thru .Ajax function which resides in one of my Android applications html pages.

I believe that is possible but I am unable to get that code done.

Below is my CostService.svc code

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System.ServiceModel;
    using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
    using System.ServiceModel.Web;
    using System.Text;
namespace SandwichServices
{
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "SandwichServices")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode     =AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class CostService
{   
    [OperationContract]
    public double CostOfSandwiches(int quantity)
    {
        return 1.25 * quantity;
    }

    // Add more operations here and mark them with [OperationContract]
}
}
```

And below is the code calling it from javascript

```
                        var Type;
                        var Url;
                        var Data;
                        var ContentType;
                        var DataType;
                        var ProcessData;
                        function WCFJSON() {
                        var qq = "3";
                        Type = "POST";
                        Url = "rent-o-buy.com/costservice.svc";
                        Data = '{"quantity": "' + qq + '"}';
                        ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                        DataType = "json";
                        ProcessData = true;
                        CallService();
                        }
                        // Function to call WCF  Service       
                        function CallService() {
                        //alert('before ajax call');
                        $.ajax({
                            type: Type, //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
                            url: Url, // Location of the service
                            data: Data, //Data sent to server
                            contentType: ContentType, // content type sent to server
                            dataType: DataType, //Expected data format from server
                            processdata: ProcessData, //True or False
                            success: function (msg) {//On Successfull service call
                                ServiceSucceeded(msg);
                            },
                            error: ServiceFailed// When Service call fails
                        });
                        //alert('after ajax call');
                        }


                         function ServiceFailed(result) {
                        alert('failed: ' + result.status + '' + result.statusText);
                        Type = null;
                        varUrl = null;
                        Data = null;
                        ContentType = null;
                        DataType = null;
                        ProcessData = null;
                    }
                    function ServiceSucceeded(result) {
                        alert('ServiceSucceeded');
                        if (DataType == "json") {
                            resultObject = result.GetUserResult;
                            alert('resultObject.length=' + resultObject.length);
                            for (i = 0; i < resultObject.length; i++) {                    
                                alert(resultObject[i]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    function ServiceFailed(xhr) {
                        alert(xhr.responseText);

                        if (xhr.responseText) {
                            var err = xhr.responseText;
                            if (err)
                                error(err);
                            else
                                error({ Message: "Unknown server error." })
                        }
                        return;
                    }
    </script>
```

I need help with the JavaScript because it does not seem to be communicating with the service.
Thanks

Comment: Please post the relevant code and tell us why you cannot get it to work or what issues you have.

Comment: Many thanks for the prompt reply.  I edited the post above with the code.  Cheers